# How to make both header and footer in collection view with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to make both header and footer in collection view in swift ?

I'm trying to combine a header and a footer together but it keep crashing, I couldn't find swift tutorial to understand it.

I don't how to return supplementary view for both rather just one .

I set them both on the storyboard (class + identifier )

```swift
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    var header: headerCell!
    var footer: footerCell!

    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
        header =
            collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind,
                withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as? headerCell
    }
    
    return header
}
```

> **Error:**
> UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier one - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> profileCC {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("one", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! profileCC

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}



override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    
    switch kind {
        
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! headerCell
        
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        return headerView
        
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "footer", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! footerCell
        
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
        return footerView
        
    default:
        
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

I hope someone will help.

Comment: Please put more information about the crash

Comment: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier one - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: identifier footer with footer cell of UICollectionReusableView and identifier header with header cell of UICollectionReusableView

Comment: @marrios Have you registered a class for your custom header and footer in code or in Interface Builder???

Comment: See updated answer to see how to register a class for a custom header or footer in code

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can make an `UICollectionViewController` to handle the `UICollectionView` and in Interface Builder activate the *Footer* and *Header* sections, then you can use the following method for preview in you `UICollectionView` the two sections added :

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    
    switch kind {
        
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath)
        
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return headerView
        
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath)
        
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return footerView
        
    default:
        
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

In the above code I put the `identifier` for the footer and header as `Header` and `Footer` for example, you can do it as you want. If you want to create a custom header or footer then you need to create a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` for each and customize it as you want.

You can register your custom footer and header classes in Interface Builder or in code with:

```
registerClass(myFooterViewClass, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "myFooterView")
```

Comment: Do you have a sample app to share?

Comment: Thanks, Mark! looking forward to new videos!

Answer (score 91):

Updated for Swift 3+

**Step 1:**

In your view controller class, register the class to be used as a header, footer, or both:

```
let collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier = "MyHeaderFooterClass"
```

**Step 2:**

If using a xib, use:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier:collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier)

collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier:collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier)
```

If not using a xib:

```
collectionView.register(MyHeaderFooterClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier)

collectionView.register(MyHeaderFooterClass.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier)
```

**Step 3:**

Create a custom header/footer class, implementation looks like:

```
import UIKit

class MyHeaderFooterClass: UICollectionReusableView {

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

    // Customize here

 }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

 }
}
```

**Step 4:** *If not using a xib, ignore*

- Create a new empty xib: "File --> New File --> Empty".
- Name it the *exact same name* as the class.  In this example: "MyHeaderFooterClass"
- Add a collection reusable view to the xib.
- Click on that object, select the Identity Inspector and change the class of that object to "MyHeaderFooterClass".

**Step 5:**
- Support that new cell in your collection view via delegate method:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                    at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return headerView

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewHeaderFooterReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return footerView

    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

**Step 6:**
Handle size / make it appear:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 180.0)
}
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 30.0)
}
```

Comment: Perfect even for Swift 5 & if you're creating everything programmatically

Comment: @mobilecat I am a little confused. In step 2 shouldn't the initialisations be vice versa for the conditions *if using a xib* and *if not using a xib* ?

Comment: for the size this worked for me: `flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100))`

Answer (score 16):

In addition to all answers above

To activate the Footer and Header sections

Select your collection then select Attributes inspector and check on the Footer and Header sections

like in photo

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just to complement the remaining answers, don't forget to allocate space for your header/footer views, otherwise `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath` **won't be called**.

Do so by implementing `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` in your collectionView datasource.

Comment: And in order to do so you need to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Answer (score 7):

After using @mobilecat code you should use this function to make the header and footer appear

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 180.0)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 30.0)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

**Xcode 11+ & iOS 13+**

I am using Xib for creating Header & Footer Views

1. Create a Xibs and Class File For Header & Footer like this (Same as Footer class) & also create xib views for both

```
class HeaderViewCV: UICollectionReusableView {

}
```

2. Register Xib Cells like this

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HeaderViewCV", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderViewCV") //elementKindSectionFooter for footerview
```

3. Header & Footer View Methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    
   switch kind {
                
   case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderViewCV", for: indexPath)
            return headerView
            
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterViewCV", for: indexPath)
            return footerView
            
     default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

4. For View Height Method for both

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 55)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 67)
}
```

5. Done all the necessary requirement for Header & Footer in CollectionView is ready

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var newAttributesForElementsInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in attributesForElementsInRect! {

            if !(attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                || attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {

                // cells will be customise here, but Header and Footer will have layout without changes.
            }

            newAttributesForElementsInRect.append(attributes)
        }

        return newAttributesForElementsInRect
    }
}


class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let headerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "HeaderCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(headerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")

        let footerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "FooterCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(footerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterCell")
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
            return headerView
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterCell", for: indexPath) as! FooterCell
            return footerView
        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 45)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 25)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you need to keep empty spaces for header and footer make an extension of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and use this code to set header or footer accordingly.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let footerValue = 150
    let headerValue = 150
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: headerValue, left: 0, bottom: footerValue, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: Hey, how can we add something in footer of collectionView? E.g I have to add uilabel in footer of uicollection. From your method i am able to create footer but don't understand how to add it. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Note that your viewController must implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout or these methods won't get called

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

following @mobilecat detailed answer, if you are using compositional collection view, add these lines when creating the layout:

```
let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44))
let headerElement = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)
```

and set the `headerElement` to your section like this:

```
 let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
 section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerElement]
```

The full code snippet is:

```
private func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0),
                                          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.2))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                           heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0))
    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    
    let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(44))
    let headerElement = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerElement]


    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    return layout
  }
```