# How to add header and footer view of UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have added the delegate function in the controller class but it won't called at the run time.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
}
```

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/

Comment: Did you register a class for the supplementary view?

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655652/how-to-make-both-header-and-footer-in-collection-view-with-swift

Comment: i have done in the objective c project 
but in swift the headerview delegate wont called at run time

Comment: Then update your question with the code that registers the class for the supplementary view.

Comment: I encounter this problem and solve by using `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` because it not specify that take zero for header and delegate didn't call

Answer (score 9):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        return headerView

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView

        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
        return footerView

    default:

        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

Comment: this delegate didnt called at run time

Comment: I'm calling this: (Swift 3)

`collectionView?.register(HeaderCollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell") `

I'm still not able to call the delegate!

Answer (score 7):

I follow this tutorial [Appcoda tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/) and update code For swift 4.0

Register the class :

```
self.collectionView.register(HeadView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeadView")
```

Delegates :

```
// For header size (required)
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:50.0)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeadView", for: indexPath)

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;
        return headerView

    default:

        fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Delegate method not called because you need to register a class for the supplementary view;

```
yourCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "collectionHeaderID")

yourCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "collectionFooterID")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout

set headerReferenceSize

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width:      self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 50)
```